# In Windows Task Manager Memory page, which value is the actual amount of system RAM?

Tags: windows, task-manager

I'm looking for an explanation of different values on the Performance / Memory page of Windows 10 / 2019 Task Manager regarding the (total) amount of RAM. There are several items that seem to mean the same thing (total RAM), but are actually showing (slightly) different values (marked red on screenshot).

The screenshot is from a virtual machine which probably adds some more complexity, but at least the answer will be more detailed.

In the screenshot I marked red the different values, that a common user would expect to mean "the amount of RAM installed" and to be the same value everywhere, but apparently they all mean something else?

[image]

The screenshot is from Windows Server 2019, but the information should apply more or less to Windows 10 too, as they shared most of code.

Comment: What does your research show?

Comment: @DanielB quite a lot of hits, but with incomplete, partial or otherwise not satisfactory answers.

Comment: Have you considered [RAMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap), it shows a lot more than Task Manager

Comment: Also if you hover over the "Memory composition" groups they'll give you more information what they are and what they're used for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on observation, I came to this conclusions.

As some virtual machines (like the one where the screenshot comes) have the feature of growing and shrinking the (virtual) RAM, I'll use the expression "actual RAM" in the meaning "amount of RAM appearing to the virtual machine as real RAM, in that moment of time".

[image]

Marked values in the image are:

1. actual RAM (updated live in Task Manager)
2. ??? , seems to never update, even after restarting Task Manager
3. actual RAM when Task manager was started, not updated until Task Manager is closed and opened again
4. ??? , does no seem to update without restarting Task Manager
5. actual RAM + swap (pagefiles.sys) , updated live

Number 3 was apparently meant to mean the graph top value, but they forgot to make it "live" for virtual (or real) machines that support live changes in RAM amount. The graph itself updates/adapts to changes of actual RAM (its range is equal to the amount of actual RAM)

On a real, common PC, the values are similar, except they never change:

1. actual RAM
2. actual RAM + hardware reserved (in other words: real RAM, e.g. on my laptop it is 32,0 GB)
3. actual RAM
4. hardware reserved (RAM used up by "motherboard" and not available to the operating system, about 200 MB on my laptop)
5. actual RAM + swap (pagefiles.sys)